# Using "extern" functions in OpenQASM3

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to understand on how to use "extern" functions in OpenQASM3 using Qiskit and the quantum devices from IBM. Judging from the link here (November 2023): https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/build/qasm-feature-table#openqasm-3-feature-table I see that at this moment at least "extern" functions currently have partial support. Can I create a setup where my custom code can be called with an "extern" call from OpenQASM even if in order to achieve this I have to override some existing function in Sampler or some other class? Can I find an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for external users to define their own extern functions currently for IBM hardware.

Comment: Considering that this is possible for extern subroutines exposed by backend devices can I create a setup where my custom code can be called with an "extern" call from OpenQASM even if in order to achieve this I have to override some existing function in Sampler or some other class?

Comment: No, this is not yet possible as it is necessary for the code to run within the control system within the coherence time of the qubit. We do not expose the capability for external users to write, compile, and, expose these at the current time.